# When I SSH I use the -i switch, do I need to do that for my GIT remote also?

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am setting up GIT on my server, when I SSH into my server I do:

```
ssh -i /path/to/key -p 30000 user@1.1.1.1
```

Now I setup GIT on the server, and I setup REMOTE like this:

```
remote add origin ssh://user@1.1.1.1:30000/path/to/git/repo/proj1
```

I'm getting the error:

push origin
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@1.1.1.1:30000/path/to/git/repos/proj1'

So far in my local repo I did:

```
touch .gitignore
git add .
git commit -m 'init'
```

And my server has a git bare in it.

**UPDATE**

```
git push origin

git push origin
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git.myhost/home/myuser/gitrepos/csf'
```

My .ssh/config:

```
Host git.myhost
        User myuser
        Hostname 1.2.3.4
        Port 30000
        IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/key_for_git
```

Comment: You don't need to specify `ssh://` for the remote, that's assumed.

Comment: are you sure? that seems odd!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about set up your host information in `.ssh/config` file; 
in this way you won't need the `-i` in both `ssh` and `git`.

**Edit**: little Googling I find this

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitTips#How_to_pass_ssh_options_in_git.3F

So the only solution other than `.ssh/config` is to use `$GIT_SSH` environment variable.

Comment: How to I use a .ssh/config file when I don't really have a HOST domain, I want to connect via SSH and server ip etc.

Comment: meaning, like: ssh://user@1.1.1.1:30000/path/to/git/repo/proj1   or would user@1.1.1.1. be my host?

Comment: Have your read the link I posted? It is the exact example for your saturation.

Comment: `Host` is simply the name you make up; Your could use IP for the `hostname`, user for `user`, port for `port`, and /path/to/key to `IdentityFile`

Comment: i didn't see port.  Oh so host is really just a friendly name, not the exact host, gotcha thanks! trying it now!

Comment: so did you solve your question or not? your friendly name is `git.rscs` but you are still pushing to `git.myhost`?

Comment: that was just a typo, i'm changing the actual name when i post the question.